# the '(' is not aligned properly when using Mono font in Emacs

Tags: fonts, align

I am using Emacs to edit. all the `(` in the picture are all at the same point on each line. But they are not aligned.

Major Mode: verilog-mode
Theme     : manoj-dark

[image]

Comment: alignment/indent will apply only for beginning of the line. to align from middle, you might have to use table mode...

Comment: Hi @MadhavanKumar, I think that is not align mode. All the `(` from `.clk` are at same point. So I think they should align if the font is fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the problem which is the `manoj-dark` theme sets the `Height` of `font-lock-function-name-face` to `1.1`. Which causes the function name's characters are 10% bigger than the `space`.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE.  As a general rule, please only ask one question per post, and then not in an answer.  Let me suggest that you edit the question out of this answer and post it as a separate question.  To provide context to the new question, you can link to the old question post (ie, this question thread).